# How jquery $('#some_id').text('some_text') works?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm now working with some `javascript` and trying to set a text in a `span` like this -

```
<span id='span_id'></span>
.....
....
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $('#span_id').text('Hello World');
</script>
```

So far I know to change/set some value/text on an html page without reloading it we have to use `ajax`. I'm wondering how does this - `$('#span_id').text('Hello World')` works here without reloading the page

Comment: Your premise that you have to refresh the page to change text in DOM elements is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the source from jQuery (specifically [manipulation.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L327)) where the function is defined:

```
text: function( value ) {
    return access( this, function( value ) {
        return value === undefined ?
            jQuery.text( this ) :
            this.empty().each( function() {
                if ( this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11 || this.nodeType === 9 ) {
                    this.textContent = value;
                }
            } );
    }, null, value, arguments.length );
```

}

It's just defining the `textContent` attribute on the selected node.  This is triggering a reflow/repaint event (as new text will take up a new amount of space) but not a full page reload.  You can read up on what the `nodeType` values mean here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType

Comment: Seems a shame that this question is being voted down,. It seems like the gut reaction is "you should already know" but this not a trivial level of complexity.

Comment: I feel like sometimes people are punished by others for what they feel they "should already know...". It's unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

Using `jQuery` the `$('#span_id')` is what identifies the element with the id of `span_id`. From there, the `text` method sets the text to `Hello World`. You don't need to reload for javascript to change the DOM. Once the page is initially loaded, the script is run, and thus changes the DOM. You don't have to reload the page.